# My heroku looks different compared to local host

Tags: heroku

This is my repo:
https://github.com/tabby-lab/My-Portfolio

I think it has to do something with the build pack but I can't seem to figure it out. It just looks like it's zoomed in on heroku.

Heroku:
https://fathomless-plains-91665.herokuapp.com/

[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO6xd.jpg)

Comment: They look roughly the same to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've detected that there is something like a magnifying glass in your browser URL field.

Try to click on this icon and select "Reset" or, if you're running a Mac, press `<Command>` + `<0>`.

I'm not sure, but it should reset zooming.

Comment: Oh.My.God.....That was it... I was doing all kinds of crazy shit and re deploying to heroku!thanks so much!

Comment: Also, do you know why this little icon "JL" is in the tab?

Comment: It's hard to say... Maybe you use favicon tag into the HTML by accident? Something like `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />`.

Or sometimes a browser caches previous favicon. It could happen in case before you were playing with another project on `localhost:3000`. Try incognito mode in your browser. If there is no icon there, then it is probably a browser cache.

Comment: Thanks!I asked my friend to check in their browser and it wasn't there so that's good. But yeah it's not in any of that. Oh well, as long as it's not showing up on anyone elses computer(: